# Generate an html fragment hyperlink which opens a new tab

Tags: html, wolfram-cloud, hyperlink

Generating a hyperlink (for later use with a cloud deployment) yields,

```
ExportString[
  Hyperlink["TEST", "http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/"], 
"HTMLFragment"]

(*"<a href=\"http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/\">TEST</a>"*)
```

When clicked, the link changes the frame/document it is in.

From [W3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp), I need the target-blank tag:

```
<a href="http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/" target="_blank">TEST</a>
```

How can I generate a link with the new tab or window behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `XMLElement` to represent the link:

```
customHyperlink[uri_, label_] := XMLElement["a", {
   "href" -> uri,
   "target" -> "_blank"
   }, label]
customHyperlink[uri_] := customHyperlink[uri, uri]
```

It works with `ExportString` just like `Hyperlink`:

```
ExportString[customHyperlink["http://mathematica.wolfram.com"], "HTMLFragment"]
```

> `"<a href=\"http://mathematica.wolfram.com\" \
>   target=\"_blank\">http://mathematica.wolfram.com</a>"`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the intricacy of cloud deployment, but I would figure that you could generate the required string "by hand" with a helped function:

```
Clear[blankhyperlink]
blankhyperlink[name_String, destination_String] := 
 "<a href=\"" <> destination <> "\" target=\"_blank\">" <> name <> "</a>"

blankhyperlink["TEST", "http://mathematica.stackexchange.com"]

(* Out: "<a href=\"http://mathematica.stackexchange.com\" target=\"_blank\">TEST</a>" *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
XMLTemplate["<a href=\"<wolfram:slot/>\" target=\"_blank\">TEST</a>"]["http://mathematica.stackexchange.com"]


CloudDeploy@
 Delayed[HTTPResponse[
   XMLTemplate[
     "<a href=\"<wolfram:slot/>\" target=\"_blank\">TEST</a>"][
     "http://mathematica.stackexchange.com"]]]
```